# Multiple triggers of same Job Quartz.NET

Tags: quartz.net

I have the following code:

```
 IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().StoreDurably().WithIdentity("J_Email", "J_Mailing").Build();         
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                .WithIdentity("MailTrigger1", "T_Mail1")
                                .StartNow()                                
                                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()
                                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(3)
                                    .RepeatForever())
                                .Build();       


            ITrigger triggernew = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                               .WithIdentity("MailTrigger", "T_Mail")
                               .StartNow()                               
                               .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()
                                   .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                                   .RepeatForever())
                               .Build();        
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job,triggernew);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job,trigger);
```

I am getting the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException'
>   occurred in Quartz.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to store Job: 'J_Mailing.J_Email',
>   because one already exists with this identification.

But I have been told that you can have multiple triggers of the same JOB.  Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add the Job to the Scheduler.

Then on the creation of the triggers, use `ForJob`.

The code below is tested.

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();


//// scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey("J_Email"));


IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyConcreteJob>().StoreDurably().WithIdentity("J_Email", "J_Mailing").Build();

scheduler.AddJob(job, true /* bool replace */ ); /* Add the given IJob to the Scheduler - with no associated ITrigger.  */


ITrigger triggerOne = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("MailTrigger1", "T_Mail1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(3)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .ForJob(job)
                    .Build();


ITrigger triggerTwo = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity("MailTrigger2", "T_Mail2")
                   .StartNow()
                   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()
                       .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                       .RepeatForever())
                   .ForJob(job)
                   .Build();


scheduler.ScheduleJob(triggerTwo);
scheduler.ScheduleJob(triggerOne);

scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: "ForJob" will get you there.

Comment: Thanks - this was extremely useful.

Comment: Quartz.net saved me from reinventing the wheel. However I have a question regarding the scenario above whereby I want to trigger the same job with different parameters. An example would be every 5 seconds I would a parameter 10 and ever hour I would recon for the hour by passing 60. However I don't ever want two instances of them running. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: For the different parameters, see ".UsingJobData("JobDetailParameter001", "Abcd1234") (for the job setup) and then this for reading the value :         public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            JobDataMap mergedMap = context.MergedJobDataMap;
            string myValue = mergedMap.GetString("JobDetailParameter001");   for non-current, research the [DisallowConcurrentExecution] attribute

Comment: Thanks dude, appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: You can also "inject" C# properties (http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html) which makes the code cleaner. E.g. instead of  JobDataMap mergedMap = context.MergedJobDataMap; string myValue = mergedMap.GetString("JobDetailParameter001");  you can simply use "JobDetailParameter001" if you define public string JobDetailParameter001 { private get; set; }

Comment: Thanks @AFD.  I didn't know that voodoo existed.

Comment: How many triggers could be added though? In my scenario I could have up to 100 triggers for a job. Would that still work fine?

Comment: You can add (experiment with) adding as many as you want.  But you increase the odds of "overlapping", perhaps race-conditions... and misfires.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43330447/214977