# Schedule job with multiple triggers in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I need to run job on 2 different schedules (morning and afternoon). I know how to run it on one schedule, but not sure how to set it so 2 schedules trigger this job

```
var saferWatchJobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<SaferWatchProcessor>().Build();
            var swtriggerMorning = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule("0 10 6 ? * MON-SUN *", cs => cs.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"))).Build();
            var swtriggerAfternoon = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule("0 10 13 ? * MON-FRI *", cs => cs.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"))).Build();
            this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(saferWatchJobDetail, swtriggerMorning);
```

According to documentation it seems like I need to use `ScheduleJob` override with `ISet<ITrigger>` but I'm not sure about 2 things:

1. What is implementing `ISet` and how do I instantiate this object?
2. What is other parameter `replace`? Not sure how should I use it. And what is the "key"? From documentation:

> If any of the given job or triggers already exist (or more
>   specifically, if the keys are not unique) and the replace parameter is
>   not set to true then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple triggers of same Job Quartz.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796696/multiple-triggers-of-same-job-quartz-net)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796696/multiple-triggers-of-same-job-quartz-net/35804345#35804345  See my answer

Answer (score 4):

granaCoder's answer didn't work for me at all. It kept throwing exceptions. Not sure why.

If you want to use triggerset, which ended up working for me, this is how you do it:

```
        var triggerSet = new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<ITrigger>();
        var saferWatchJobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<SaferWatchProcessor>().Build();
        var swtriggerMorning = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule("0 10 6 ? * MON-SUN *", cs => cs.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"))).Build();
        var swtriggerAfternoon = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule("0 10 13 ? * MON-FRI *", cs => cs.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"))).Build();
        triggerSet.Add(swtriggerMorning);
        triggerSet.Add(swtriggerAfternoon);
        this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(saferWatchJobDetail, triggerSet, true);
```