# Quartz.net durable and clustered

Tags: quartz.net, quartz

The config:

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ChengongDemo" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceId" value="AUTO" />

    <!--线程池-->
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="5" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />

    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="myDb" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDb.connectionString" value="Data Source=192.168.15.23;Initial Catalog=Quartz;User ID=sa;Password=123456789" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.myDb.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />

    <!-- 集群-->
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.Clustered" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval" value="600" />
  </quartz>
```

The code:

```
 public static void Run()
           {
                ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                Sched = sf.GetScheduler();

            var jobDetail = new JobKey("job1", "group1");
            var triggerKey = new TriggerKey("trigger1", "group1");
            if (!Sched.CheckExists(jobDetail) && !Sched.CheckExists(jobDetail))
            {
                var job = JobBuilder.Creaenter code herete<TestJob>()
                  .WithIdentity(jobDetail)
                  .Build();

                var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                .ForJob(job.Key)
                .WithCronSchedule("*/2 * * ? * *")
                .Build();

                Sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }

            Sched.Start();
        }
```

The Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wf2l.png)

The service run normally. I shundown for a few seconds,Then I start again.The 
Job ran several times at the same time.

Why？Someone can help me?Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disallow "running at the same time", then apply the

```
DisallowConcurrentExecution
```

attribute

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

As in

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyDoesNotRunConcurrentlyJob : IJob
{
```

HOWEVER, I think what you are experiencing is your first experience with a "misire" , or a job didn't execute on the utopia schedule....then there are rules around that.

I would read the below URL.  While its for the java-quartz (and quartz.net is a "port over" (to .net), the below is the best mini resource for understanding misfires.

he even mentions your specific case

"the scheduler itself was down"

http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html

I will copy the header information here, in case the url ever "dies", you (or more likely future readers) can use the below text to search for the article.

***Quartz scheduler misfire instructions explained***
Sometimes Quartz is not capable of running your job at the time when you desired. There are three reasons for that:
all worker threads were busy running other jobs (probably with higher priority)
the scheduler itself was down
the job was scheduled with start time in the past (probably a coding error)